unreachable code not reported in typescript
Given the following typescript code:
function foo(arg: boolean): string {
    if(arg){
        return 'abc';
    } else {
        return arg ? 'cde' : 'def';
    }
}

the cde is unreachable, but neither IntelliJ, SonarLint nor TSLint prints a warning.
If I replace the arg with an explicit arg == true in both places, IntelliJ shows an TS2367 error for the arg == true in the (second) return.
function foo(arg: boolean): string {
    if(arg == true){
        return 'abc';
    } else {
        return arg == true ? 'cde' : 'def'; // "arg == true" marked with TS2367 error
    }
}


How can I convince either tool to also report an error without the explicit equals check?
